# reorder php object based on one of its property values

Tags: php, sorting, object

let's say I have an object, `$obj`, that after this `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach($obj as $row){
    echo 'file_id:'.$row->file_id.'-name:'.$row->name.'<br>';
}
```

would look like this:

```
file_id:321-name:321-is-good
file_id:322-name:322-is-better
file_id:323-name:323-is-best
```

How can I sort `$obj` such that I can choose what is the first `echo`'d `$row`? For example, if I plugged in `322` somewhere, the result would look like this:

```
file_id:322-name:322-is-better
file_id:323-name:323-is-best
file_id:321-name:321-is-good
```

and if I plugged in `323`:

```
file_id:323-name:323-is-best
file_id:321-name:321-is-good
file_id:322-name:322-is-better
```

I know it probably involves `usort()` but I can't wrap my head around what needs to be done.

thoughts?

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to sort on `file_id` at a specific start, appending what comes before, which is also sorted on `file_id`:

```
$sort = '323';
usort($arr,function($a,$b) use ($sort) {
   //normal sorting for low-ids after high-ids
   if($a->file_id < $sort && $a->file_id < $sort){
      return strcmp($a->file_id,$b->file_id);
   } 
   //if only $a is smaller $a should be later
   if($a->file_id < $sort) return 1;
   //if only $b is smaller $a should be earlier
   if($b->file_id < $sort) return -1;
   //both above $sort, sort normally
   return strcmp($a->file_id,$b->file_id);
 });
```

---

Working example with an Object instead of a Array:

```
<?php
//build a test with arrays is easier;
$arr = new ArrayObject(array(
    array('file_id' => '321','name' => '321 is good'),
    array('file_id' => '322','name' => '322 is better'),
    array('file_id' => '323','name' => '323 is best')));
//cast all to object for purposes of testing objects
foreach($arr as &$val) $val = (object)$val;
//when you used a reference _always_ unset... trust me on this one
unset($val);

$sort = '323';
// we define the callback separately because for this test we use it more then once
// don't pay much attention to the reference as &$sort, this is just to alter it in 
// multiple tests, and should not be needed in the actual implementation.

$callback = function($a,$b) use (&$sort) {
   //normal sorting for low-ids after high-ids
   if($a->file_id < $sort && $b->file_id < $sort){ //$a & $b indeed, not $a twice ;)
      return strcmp($a->file_id,$b->file_id);
   }
   //if only $a is smaller $a should be later
   if($a->file_id < $sort) return 1;
   //if only $b is smaller $a should be earlier
   if($b->file_id < $sort) return -1;
   //both above $sort, sort normally
   return strcmp($a->file_id,$b->file_id);
};

//322 first:
$sort='322';
$arr->uasort($callback);
var_dump($arr);

//323 first:
$sort='323';
$arr->uasort($callback);
var_dump($arr);

//321 again first:
$sort='321';
$arr->uasort($callback);
var_dump($arr);

//non-existing:
$sort='400';
$arr->uasort($callback);
var_dump($arr);



object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "322"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "322 is better"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "323"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "323 is best"
    }
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "321"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "321 is good"
    }
  }
}
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "323"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "323 is best"
    }
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "321"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "321 is good"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "322"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "322 is better"
    }
  }
}
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "321"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "321 is good"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "322"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "322 is better"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "323"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "323 is best"
    }
  }
}
object(ArrayObject)#1 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "321"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "321 is good"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "322"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "322 is better"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["file_id"]=>
      string(3) "323"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "323 is best"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: -@Wrikken, yes `$sort` will be defined on the fly, thank you let me try your code...

Comment: I have not tested it, so I am not responsible for any parse or other errors, but it should help get the idea across ;)

Comment: -@Wrikken, so do I need to typecast `$obj` as an $array first? Also, i'm having trouble returning the re-ordered `$obj`. Do I just do this: `$obj=usort($obj, function($a...`?

Comment: -@wrikken, i'm confused, this is is not keeping the `names` together with the `file_ids`. Also, `321` is always coming first, would you mind clarifying your answer to address these 2 problems? thanks,

Comment: Might have to do with the first if (accidentally checka `$a` twice instead of `$a`and `$b` (which you tried to edit in). I'll go to the actual code and try to make a working example.

Comment: Aha, I only now see your 'list' of rows was an object itself, missed that the first time around. Yes, for sorting to work you either need an array (or, define a custom `next()` & others for the `Iterator` interface), or extend something like an `ArrayObject` (which was what I did for this example).