# PHP: sort an object on the index positions of one of its property values

Tags: php, sorting, object

I have an object with 3 properties. I'd like to input a number 1,2, or 3 (0,1,or 2 is fine too) and sort the object in ascending numerical order based on one its property values.

Here's what my object looks like:

```
var_dump($obj);

array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (92) { 
        ["file_id"]=> string(1) "6" 
        ["name"]=> string(1) "1st item" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#26 (92) { 
        ["file_id"]=> string(1) "7"    
        ["name"]=> "2nd item"
    } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#27 (92) { 
        ["file_id"]=> string(1) "8" 
        ["name"]=> "3rd item"
    }
}
```

If I input 1, then the output would look like this:

```
file_id    name
 6      1st item
 7      2nd item
 8      3rd item
```

If I input 2, then the output would be:

```
7  2nd item
8  3rd item
6  1st item
```

If I input 3, then the output would be:

```
8  3rd item
6  1st item
7  2nd item
```

**This question is nearly identical to one [I asked earlier on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060200/reorder-php-object-based-on-one-of-its-property-values) , the sole exception being that I need to `sort()` on the index positions of the `file_id` values and not on the `file_id` values themselves. I.e., I need to sort on 1,2,3 and not 6,7,8.**

If you are particularly excited about this question (yes I realize this is unlikely), i'd be curious to know what the numbers `25` and `92` stand for in the output: `object(stdClass)#25 (92)`.

Comment: Are you using a `var_dump` or a `print_r` to display the object info?

Comment: @Matt `var_dump()`. Is converting `$obj` to an array needed for indexing? I'm using [Codeigniter `query->result()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) which returns "an array of objects".

Comment: To answer your question about the numbers in the `var_dump()`, I think the `#25` is the resource ID of the object; `92` may be the size of the object in bytes.

Comment: The second number (92) seems to be the number of properties of that object. I.e. `class A { protected $p1; }` -> (1), `class B { protected $p1; protected $p2; }` -> (2) and so on. This also applies to properties that are added only at runtime (i.e. outside the class contract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question *after* sorting an array by some property you want to *rotate* the array so that e.g. the array (1,2,3,4) becomes (3,4,1,2).
I'm using string literals as array members in this example, switching to objects is trivial.

```
<?php
$sortedData = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'); // getting an array like this has been solved by the answers to your previous question
$foo = rotate($sortedData, 2);
var_dump($foo);


function rotate($source, $n) {
    // could use some pre-checks...
    return array_merge(
        array_slice($source, $n, NULL, true),
        array_slice($source, 0, $n, true)
    );
}
```

prints

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
```

Comment: -@VolkerK, thanks! nice work, your `rotate()` function did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Write 3 compare functions, for each attribute one, switch according to the input value, which compare function is used

edit:
the numbers are the PHP internal object id (`#25`) and the size of the object.

quick example:

```
function compare_1($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->file_id, $b->file_id);
}
// compare_2, compare_3 accordingly as needed with your objects

switch ($input) {
  case 1:
    $compareFunctionName = 'compare_1';
    break;
  case 2:
    $compareFunctionName = 'compare_2';
    break;
  case 3:
    $compareFunctionName = 'compare_3';
    break;
  default:
    throw new Exception('wrong Parameter: input is ' . $input);
 }

 usort($objectArray, $compareFunctionName);

 var_dump($objectArray);
```

Comment: -@cypherabe, thanks for taking a shot at this, there is an unknown # of objects so `compare_1, compare_2,...` isn't realistic. Any work arounds for that?

Comment: maybe I didn't understand your intention... my approach is that `compare_1` etc should be functions that compare a specific attribute on all objects: `compare_1` compares `$obj->file_id`, `compare_2` compares `$obj->name` etc.. the number of objects in the array doesn't matter, as long as the objects are similar. You need to have some knowledge about the target objects to write this.  - just saw VolkerK's answer...maybe i didn't catch the rotate part?

Comment: -@cypherabe, oh I understand what you did now. Its just that your code doesn't enable to input a value. I'm looking for something like @VolkerK's `rotate()` function where you can input the value `$n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to complete this task

Step1: remove the value of the inputted index from the array array_search() and unset function

Step2: Sort the array by using sort function

Step 3: Add the removed value to the top of the array by using push/pop function

For more knowledge on array functions visit http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.com